# Separate name for print without newline

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, output

Some programming languages e.g. Pascal and Java have a keyword or standard library function e.g. `print` to output a value, and a separate name `println` to output with a newline, but this has the disadvantage of giving the shorter/more obvious name to the behavior you don't usually want.

Other languages e.g. Basic and Python use `print` for the behavior you do usually want and have a special syntax such as a trailing `;` or `,` to suppress the newline when required. This works, but one could argue that it would be more elegant/transparent to have different names for the two behaviors.

Are there - or have there ever been - any languages where output of a value with newline is spelled `print`, and there is a separate name for output without newline?

Comment: (Maybe this question would be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com?)

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's [`puts`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/puts.htm) prints the given string *and* the trailing newline by default, unless it's passed the `-nonewline` command-line option.